# How to get the android xml view element id attribute in java code

Tags: android

Suppose I have an xml definition for a button with id as `@+id/send_button`

How I can get this id attribute value in Java code? I tried getXXX methods on `AttributeSet` class but doesn't provide any value which has "send_button" in it.

Edit1:

Let me make it a little bit more clear.

I am creating a custom `View` component and I want to know what's the id value that the user of this component provided in xml file.

Edit2:

I'm not using custom attributes due to a particular reason but using

```
<mycomponent
     android:id="@+id/my_id"/>
```

Edit 3:

There is a `getIdAttribute()` method on `AttributeSet` but it  just doesn't work. Anyone know any reason?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you are building a custom view and after you retrieved this view you want to obtain the id of this view. Why and how you are doing this is still not very clear to me.

But if your custom view is a subclass of View there should be a [getId()](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29) method that will return the identifier assigned to that view.

Answer (score 2):

I still haven't figured out to do exactly what you are asking, but the getTag method of View will retrieve the string that you set in your XML element via "android:tag".

So... in essence it's the same effect, if you don't mind having that extra attribute in your XML.

```
<mycomponent
     android:id="@+id/my_id"
     android:tag="my_id"
/>
```

and then in your code...

```
String nodeId = myComponentInstance.getTag();
```